# Micronaut Clubs microservice run time error

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to run this https://github.com/alvarosanchez/micronaut-workshop micronaut workshop example to with JDK 11 and Micronaut 1.0.2

Updated few dependency, its compile fine. when I run its throwing below error.

```
21:27:18.607 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Failed to inject value for parameter [objectMapper] of class: io.micronaut
.jackson.convert.ArrayNodeToArrayConverter

Path Taken: new ArrayNodeToArrayConverter([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [objectMapper] of class: io.micronaut.jackson.convert.ArrayNodeToAr
rayConverter

Path Taken: new ArrayNodeToArrayConverter([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:981)
        at io.micronaut.jackson.convert.$ArrayNodeToArrayConverterDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1329)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:2237)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfTypeInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2165)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:752)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:522)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:313)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeTypeConverters(DefaultApplicationContext.java:339)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:193)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2033)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:156)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:141)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:67)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:271)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:257)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
        at clubs.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.jackson.convert.ArrayNodeToArrayConverter]

Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory, io.micronaut.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory]
Path Taken: new ArrayNodeToArrayConverter([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1343)
```

I have my code here https://github.com/sfgroups/micronaut-codes/tree/master/micronaut-workshop-ex02

How to fix this run time error?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the config at https://github.com/sfgroups/micronaut-codes/blob/9013a3daeb544cbc040f42091c2ff7995385b6a4/micronaut-workshop-ex02/build.gradle#L29 your project is using Micronaut 1.0.2.

```
mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.0.2'
```

At https://github.com/sfgroups/micronaut-codes/blob/9013a3daeb544cbc040f42091c2ff7995385b6a4/micronaut-workshop-ex02/build.gradle#L56 you are pulling in the `1.0.0.RC2` version of `discovery-client`, which is incompatible with Micronaut 1.0.2.

```
compile group: 'io.micronaut', name: 'discovery-client', version: '1.0.0.RC2'
```

You will want to update that version to 1.0.2 and will want to reference `micronaut-discovery-client` instead of `discovery-client` (the module name changed after RC2).  The simplest way to express that would be something like this:

```
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-discovery-client'
```

Once you fix that, you will see other problems exist in your project, but the above fixes the issue described in the question.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have to add `org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.9.Final` file to run.